# Apache Superset 'Unable to Connect to SQL Server 2017' which is enabled with TLS v1.2

Tags: sql-server, apache-superset, pymssql

I am using apache-superset 0.35.2 to connect to SQL Server 2017 and whenever I turned-on TLS v1.2 of the SQL Server, I get the following:

> OperationalError: (20009, b'DB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive server is unavailable or does not exist...

When I turn it back to TLS 1.0 it works fine. I have already tried using pyodbc but wouldn't work either. The `Encrypt=yes` URI parameter is not recognized too. I also tried other `connect_args` parameters like `sslmode` in the Extras field but are not recognized either.

I am using pymssql 2.2.2